New row violates row-level security policy .NET API on Supasbase file upload
I get this error while uploading files on Supabase storage, again Supabase storage not table :

new row violates row-level security policy

This is the code I am using in .NET:
internal sealed class StorageRepository : IStorageRepository
{
    private readonly Client _client;

    public StorageRepository(Client client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    
    public async Task<string> SaveFileAsync(
       byte[] file,
       string identifier,
       string bucketName)
    {

        var result = await _client
                .Storage
                .From(bucketName)
                .Upload(
                     data: file,
                     supabasePath: identifier);

        return result;
    }
}

This is complete error with detailed exception :

new row violates row-level security policy at Supabase.Storage.Extensions.HttpClientProgress.UploadAsync(HttpClient client, Uri uri, Stream stream, Dictionary`2 headers, Progress`1 progress) at Supabase.Storage.StorageFileApi.UploadOrUpdate(Byte[] data

I have tried by adding a new policy which allows only authenticated user to { SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, UPDATE } but still it did not work:


May this GitHub answer be of any help? https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/3389#discussioncomment-1412365

could you please share the detais or code you used to add the new policy?

@EspressoCode I have not written any code, just used the existing policy "Give users access to a folder only to authenticated users"

@AstridE. that GitHub discussion helped, can you add it as an answer, I executed two queries given in that answer

A question regarding new row violates row-level security policy was asked by  lucasmrl on Supabase's GitHub in 2021. lucasmrl answered their own question with some insight and a suggestion for how to handle the situation. Maybe that post can be useful?

To sum it up:
Scenario

The user creates an account and a public bucket containing a folder
The user tries to upload an image with the following code:

const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
    .from("bucket ID")
    .upload("file name", file, { cacheControl: "3600" });


The user receives an error message referencing a table and a security policy, both of which the user does not expect to exist:


"new row violates row-level security policy for table "objects"" statusCode: "42501"

Insight
Even if the bucket is "public", you still need to set up policies
Policy suggestion
To let people VIEW files in a bucket and UPLOAD files to a bucket, execute the following SQL queries:

VIEW: create select policy

create policy "Public Access Bucket Images Get"
on storage.objects for select
using ( bucket_id = 'bucket ID' );


UPLOAD: create insert policy

create policy "Public Access Bucket Images Post"
on storage.objects for insert
with check ( bucket_id = 'bucket ID' );


More on creating policies in Supabase in the docs.
